# TreeMap with (String,ArrayList<String,Int>)

Tags: java, arraylist, treemap, stemming, data-preprocessing

I am trying to read an input file. Each value of the input file is inserted into the TreeMap as

1. If word is not existing: Insert the word to the treemap and associate the word with an ArrayList(docId, Count).
2. If the Word is present in the TreeMap, then check if the current DocID matches within the ArrayList and then increase the count.

THe
For the ArrayList, I created another class as below:

```
public class CountPerDocument
{
    private final String documentId;
    private final int count;
    
    CountPerDocument(String documentId, int count)
    {

        this.documentId = documentId;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getDocumentId()
    {
        return this.documentId;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.count;
    }

}
```

After that, I am trying to print the TreeMap into a text file as  <DocID - Count>
Not sure what I am doing wrong here, but the output I get is as follows:

```
The Stem is todai:[CountPerDocument@5caf905d, CountPerDocument@27716f4, CountPerDocument@8efb846, CountPerDocument@2a84aee7, CountPerDocument@a09ee92, CountPerDocument@30f39991]
```

Wondering if anyone can guide me what i am doing wrong and if my method isn't correct what am i supposed to do?

```
public class StemTreeMap
{
    private static final String r1 = "\\$DOC";
    private static final String r2 = "\\$TITLE";
    private static final String r3 = "\\$TEXT";
    private static Pattern p1,p2,p3;
    private static Matcher m1,m2,m3;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedReader rd,rd1;
        String docid = null;
        String id;
        int tf = 0;
        //CountPerDocument cp = new CountPerDocument(docid, count);
        List<CountPerDocument> ls = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String,List<CountPerDocument>> mp = new TreeMap<>();
        
        try
        {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            rd1= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            int docCount = 0;
            String line = rd.readLine();
            p1 = Pattern.compile(r1);
            p2 = Pattern.compile(r2);
            p3 = Pattern.compile(r3);
            while(line != null)
            {
                m1 = p1.matcher(line);
                m2 = p2.matcher(line);
                m3 = p3.matcher(line);
                if(m1.find())
                {
                    docid = line.substring(5, line.length());
                    docCount++;
                    //System.out.println("The Document ID is :");
                    //System.out.println(docid);
                    line = rd.readLine();
                }
                if(m2.find()||m3.find())
                {
                    line = rd.readLine();
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!(mp.containsKey(line))) // if the stem is not on the TreeMap
                    {
                        //System.out.println("The stem is not present in the tree");
                        tf = 1;
                        ls.add(new CountPerDocument(docid,tf));
                        mp.put(line, ls);   
                        line = rd.readLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(ls.indexOf(docid) > 0) //if its last entry matches the current document number
                        {
                            //System.out.println("The Stem is present for the same docid so incrementing docid");
                            tf = tf+1;
                            ls.add(new CountPerDocument(docid,tf));
                            line = rd.readLine();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //System.out.println("Stem is present but not the same docid so inserting new docid");
                            tf = 1;
                            ls.add(new CountPerDocument(docid,tf)); //set did to the current document number and tf to 1
                            line = rd.readLine();
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            rd.close();
            System.out.println("The Number of Documents in the file is:"+ docCount);
            
            //Write to an output file
            String l = rd1.readLine();
            File f = new File("dictionary.txt");
            if (f.createNewFile())
            {
                System.out.println("File created: " + f.getName());
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
                Path path = Paths.get("dictionary.txt");
                Files.deleteIfExists(path);
                System.out.println("Deleted Existing File:: Creating New File");
                f.createNewFile();    
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("dictionary.txt");
            fw.write("The Total Number of Stems: " + mp.size() +"\n");
            
            fw.close();
            System.out.println("The Stem is todai:" + mp.get("todai"));
            
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        
    }
        

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define the function *String toString()* in your class *CountPerDocument*. So, when you try to print a CountPerDocument variable, the default printed value is CountPerDocument@hashcode.

To decide how to represent a *CountPerDocument* variable in your code, add in your class the next function:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return "<" + this.getDocumentId() + ", " + this.getCount() + ">";
}
```

Comment: Hi I added the functio. When i try to print it i get the following output:
accept=>[LA010190-0001-1, LA010190-0001-1, LA010190-0001-1, LA010190-0001-1, LA010190-0001-1, LA010190-0001-1, LA010190-0001-1] 
Instead of printing just say accept => LA010190-0001-1
It is printing everything in the List. Is there anyway i can fix this?

Comment: I am using this to print the values:
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List<CountPerDocument>>> iterator = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    
   Map.Entry<String, List<CountPerDocument>> entry = null;
    
   while(iterator.hasNext())
   {
       
       entry = iterator.next();
       fw.write(entry.getKey() + "=>" + entry.getValue() + "\n" );
   }

Answer (score 0):

Try to override toString method in CountPerDocument. Something like this:

```
public class CountPerDocument
{
    private final String documentId;
    private final int count;
    
    CountPerDocument(String documentId, int count)
    {

        this.documentId = documentId;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getDocumentId()
    {
        return this.documentId;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return documentId + "-" + count;
    }
}
```